# What does "Construct a chain of nonsingular matrices $C(t)$ linking $C$ to an orthogonal $Q$" mean?

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the second part of this question asking me to do?

> 1. For ${C} = \begin{bmatrix}2 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$ and $ A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$, confirm that $C^{T}AC$ has eigenvalues of the same signs as A.
> 2. **Construct a chain of nonsingular matrices $C(t)$ linking $C$ to an orthogonal $Q$.**
> 3. Why is it impossible to construct a nonsingular chain linking $C$ to the identity matrix?

(Source: Gilbert Strang, *Linear Algebra and Its Applications* 4e, 6.2.33. I inserted the question numbers for clarity.)

For context, the section is on tests for positive definiteness, and I believe this question is supposed to illustrate something about the law of inertia.

But I'm not sure what the author means by "linking" to an orthogonal matrix, or whether the notation $C(t)$ is supposed to indication a function (of what?) or multiplication or something else. I ignored the $t$ entirely and answered,

> 1. $ A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ has $\lambda = 0, 2$; $C^T AC = \begin{bmatrix}2 & 2 \\ -1 & -1\end{bmatrix}$ has $\lambda = 0, 1$ (same signs) ✔
> 2. With $Q = I$, $C = Q\begin{bmatrix}2 &  \\  & -1\end{bmatrix}Q^T$. This "links" $C$ to an orthogonal $Q$. (?)
> 3. Can't link $C$ to $I$ because their eigenvalues have different signs. ✔

But the answer key says this:

> 1. $A$ and $C^{T}AC$ have $\lambda_1 > 0, \lambda_2 = 0$
> 2. $C(t) = tQ + (1 - t)QR, Q = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & -1\end{bmatrix}, R = \begin{bmatrix}2 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$
> 3. $C$ has one positive and one negative eigenvalue, but $I$ has two positive eigenvalues.

I'm not sure where $R$ came from or why he inserts the $t$ where he does. Can anyone shed some light on how I should read the original question?

Comment: They want $C(t)$ to be a continuous function of a real parameter $t$ which values are $2\times 2$ matrices, and such that $C(0)=C$ and $C(1)=Q$. A parametrization like $ta+(1-t)b$ is the line segment between $a$ and $b$ in a vector space. $R$ probably got the name and value from the [QR decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition).

Comment: The answer that they gave to (3) looks more like a hint than a complete answer. I would look at the the determinant (product of the eigenvalues), which would be a continuous function of $t$ and would have to be negative for $t=0$ and positive for $t=1$. Therefore, for some intermediate $t$ it would have to be zero.

Comment: @conditionalMethod Couldn't you then link C to I by using Q = I and R = $\begin{bmatrix}2 &  \\  & -1\end{bmatrix}Q^T$, with C(t) taking the same form given at (2)? But the answer to (3) says this should be impossible.

Comment: You can link them, but the argument above shows that some matrix $C(t_0)$ for some $t_0$ will be singular (determinant equal to zero).

Comment: Ahh, I see. For some intermediate t, the bottom-right entry of C(t) will go to zero and you will have a singular C.